# how to use multilanguage in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, multilingual

How to create multilanguage app in yii2?
Is there any preinstall message in yii2?

*config:*

```
'language' => 'es',
'components' => [
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                //'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'ru-RU',

                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

view :

```
echo \Yii::t('app', 'I am a message!');
$username = 'Alexander';
echo \Yii::t('app', 'Hello, {username}!', [
    'username' => $username,
]);
```

Comment: You seriously need this guide: http://www.codefc.com/generate-yii2-framework-multi-language/

Comment: are you use basic app or advance app template ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Edit config.php in frontend or backend

```
'language' => 'ru',
'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

create `app.php` in `frontend/messages/ru/app.php` or `backend/messages/ru/app.php`

View:

```
echo \Yii::t('app', 'I am a message!');
```

Comment: doesn't work please participate in chat !